# Find a specific record by field value in DevExpress VerticalGrid

Tags: devexpress

Scenario: DevExpress VerticalGrid with LayoutStyle = MultiRecordView; it is bound to a System.Data.DataTable (e.g. VGridControl1.DataSource = MyDataTable).

The grid contains records of 5000 customers. We want to set the record where the CompanyName field starts with the letters 'Foo' as the focused record. Users want to be able to type a few letters of the company-name into a text-box on the form, hit a button, and then have the Vertical Grid bring the matching record into focus, without eliminating all of the other records. They want to do a "seek" not a filter. The underlying datasource would already be sorted by CompanyName.

*ADDENDUM: Also, they don't want to have to click on the sought record before they do another such search; and they want it to work even after they have scrolled the grid horizontally with the horizontal scroll bar. *

Does the Vertical Grid have any helper methods that would help with this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

With the vertical grid bound to the DefaultView of a DataTable,  one can iterate the DataRowViews in the DataView and examine the relevant column for a string match, returning the recordindex of the matched row, and then doing this:

```
        vGridControl1.FocusedRecord =  {record index of the matching row}
```